# htaccess for URLS

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Can anyone let me know how i can redirect all urls so they include a new path.

For example, on my old site i have a urls like this:

```
http://www.example.com/tag/tag-title1/
http://www.example.com/tag/tag-title2/
http://www.example.com/tag/tag-title3/
```

I now need all of these to be redirected to:

```
http://www.example.com/waterblog/tag/tag-title1
http://www.example.com/waterblog/tag/tag-title2
http://www.example.com/waterblog/tag/tag-title3
```

So really all i need to do is add /waterblog/ before the /tag/ on all URLS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^((?!waterblog/).*)$ waterblog/$1 [NC,R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

> So really all i need to do is add /waterblog/ before the /tag/ on all URLS.

You can use this simple rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(tag/.*)$ /waterblog/$1
```